# TextField(_:text:axis:) breaks keyboard avoidance inside ScrollView in iOS 16

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

Automatic keyboard avoidance seems to work fine if it's a regular `TextField` (i.e. one that doesn't expand on an `axis`), whether or not it is contained in a `ScrollView`

Keyboard avoidance also seems to work with the new `TextField(_:text:axis)` introduced in iOS 16 if it's simply placed in a `VStack` without being wrapped in a `ScrollView`. It will even continue to avoid the keyboard correctly as the height expands with more text.

But I can't seem to get keyboard avoidance to work with `TextField(_:text:axis)` if it is placed inside a `ScrollView`

I can employ the hacky method of using a `ScrollViewReader` combined with `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(400))` to wrap the `proxy.scrollTo()` when the `TextField` is focused. This sort of works when you first focus the field, but I can't seem to get the `ScrollView` to continue to adjust its position as the `TextField` expands.

Here is an example:

```swift
struct KeyboardAvoidingView: View {
    @State var text = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Color.red
                        .frame(height: 400)
                    Color.blue
                        .frame(height: 400)
                    TextField("Name", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
                        .padding(.vertical)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(400)) { 
                                withAnimation(.default) {
                                    proxy.scrollTo(0)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
                            proxy.scrollTo(0)   // This doesn't seem to do anything
                        }
                    Spacer()
                        .frame(height: 0)
                        .id(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess I'm wondering whether this is expected behavior, or a bug. And regardless if it's one or the other, I'm wondering if I can have an auto-expanding text field inside a scroll view that I can make avoid the keyboard even as the height of the field expands?

---

**UPDATE:** It turns out, the issue was with placing the `TextField` inside a `VStack` instead of a `LazyVStack`. I assume `ScrollView` doesn't know what to do with just a regular `VStack` in certain situations. If I replace the `VStack` with a `LazyVStack` in my example, everything works as expected!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I answered the question with the update posted above. The issue was with using `VStack` instead of `LazyVStack`

Answer (score 0):

This is a long time known bug in the `TextField` component, but you may achieve the desired behavior by using an `anchor: .bottom` in the `proxy.scrollTo` call of your `onChange`.

it'll look like this:

```swift
// ...
TextField("Name", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
    .padding(.vertical)
    .onTapGesture {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(400)) { 
            withAnimation(.default) {
                proxy.scrollTo(0)
            }
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: text) { newValue in
        // This will always scroll to the bottom of the text editor, 
        // just make sure to pass the right value in the first parameter
        // that will identify your TextEditor
        proxy.scrollTo(MyTextEditorId, anchor: .bottom)   
    }
// ...
```

You may need some additional work to handle the editing of upper parts of the text editor when it's taller than your screen

Comment: Surprisingly, this does not work. If I start typing without further scrolling, the ScrollView does not automatically scroll to the bottom of the vertically-expanding TextField. If I manually scroll the ScrollView a little bit, then the next time I type a key, it will correctly scroll to the bottom. Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm still not doing something correctly. I do have the proxy scrolling to the ID of the TextField itself. And again, I do not have this problem at all if the TextField does not have an `axis` parameter, nor if the TextField with `axis` is not inside a ScrollView.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. This issue has been hunting one of my projects for a while now. We had come back and forth in using the SwiftUI's TextField or having a UIViewRepresentable wrapping a UIKit's UITextField. This solution was the midterm :T